# Removing a character from folder/filenames recursively

Tags: python

I started to write a script to remove illegal chars from a linux os walk. Starting with the files, then the folders. Here is what I have so far -

```
import sys
import os
import re

# List of illegal chars to run through to replace in the filesystem walk
chars = ['~', '*', '\\', ':', '<', '>', '|', '?', '"']

def ReplaceChars(value):
    for c in chars:
        value = value.replace(c, '')
    return value

def RenamePath(path):
    newFilePath = ReplaceChars(path)
    os.rename(path, newFilePath)

def WalkFileSystem(dirroot):
    # Main Walk Through File System
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirroot, topdown=False):
        for name in files:
            searchObj = re.search(r'[%s]' % ''.join(chars), os.path.join(root, name))
            if searchObj:
                RenamePath(os.path.join(root, name))

        for name in dirs:
            searchObj = re.search(r'[%s]' % ''.join(chars), os.path.join(root, name))
            if searchObj:
                RenamePath(os.path.join(root, name))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Calls the WalkFileSystem Function
    WalkFileSystem('/TestFolder/')
```

It does work under some circumstances. The issue is, If I had a dir name like *test/ os.rename doesn't like it because it if tries to rename a file under that directory it's not breaking that wildcard in the path (I guess thats the issue)

Two Questions -

- How Can I fix that issue from happening in this case?
- Is this the most Pythonic way of doing this or am I losing the plot here?

Update With Working Example

```
import argparse
import os
import re

# List of illegal chars to run through to replace in the filesystem walk
chars = ['~', '*', '\\', ':', '<', '>', '|', '?', '"']

def ReplaceChars(value):
    for c in chars:
        value = value.replace(c, '')
    return value


def RenamePath(root, path):
    newFilePath = ReplaceChars(path)
    os.rename(os.path.join(root, path), os.path.join(root, newFilePath))


def WalkFileSystem(dirroot):
    # Main Walk Through File System
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirroot, topdown=False):

    for name in dirs:
        searchObj = re.search(r'[%s]' % ''.join(chars), name)
        if searchObj:
            RenamePath(root, name)


    for name in files:
        searchObj = re.search(r'[%s]' % ''.join(chars), name)
        if searchObj:
            RenamePath(root, name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Calls the WalkFileSystem Function
    WalkFileSystem('/home/mpashby/Scripts/TestFolder/')
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's coz, when your script runs RenamePath, It does something like this:

```
>>> os.rename(str('/testdir/*test/h.txt'), '/testdir/test/h.txt')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

you are trying to rename the path using a directory that doesn't exist(/testdir/test/h.txt) yet, hence you'll get an error

Below one works fine, though.

```
>>> os.rename(str('/testdir/*test/h.txt'), '/testdir/*test/g.txt')
>>>
```

but, you don't want any special characters, so, I'd say first remove the special characters from your directory paths before doing it on the files, that way, you don't get 'no such file or dir' errors.

Comment: I did think of that originally and decided to walk the paths first from the bottom up. It still returns an error.

Comment: Can you print path, newFilePath just before you call os.rename(path, newFilePath) and share what it prints right before raising the exception ?

Comment: Your suggestion was completely correct in this context. Printing the src and dst in the os.rename call helped me understand the issue. Looking at the path I could see my script is changing the whole path including if the dir includes any different chars. This was throwing these errors on my test directory. Updated Question With Working Example.